# How to connect to my remote MySQL server with R 3.1.1

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I am new to R and RStudio and I am wondering if I have to have a local installation of MySQL.

I am working on baseball sabermetrics and have already have a Lahman Database set up on my remote server.  All I want to do in integrate this with my R/RStudio, so I don't have to lug my computer to school an back. Does anyone know if the RODBC will work remotely? Or, even if RMySQL will work?  It seems getting connection with a x64 Windows based implementation is cumbersome enough.

Is RStudio server the best work around?  RStudio as a SAAS just doesn't seem efficient or as smooth to use.
OS:
WINDOWS 8.1

R:
3.1.1

Credentials ( I know it's not secure, but if you wanna give it a shot, then cool)

```
MySQL version = MySQL 5.5
Server: 68.178.217.14
Hosted: LahmanDB.db.6663351.hostedresource.com
Database: LahmanDB
User: LahmanDB
Password: Qwerty1!
```

Comment: If you can connect to the database from your local computer, in most situations you will be able to connect from R on said computer.

Comment: If you are into baseball data, I recommend you check out the pitchRx package, it might be of help: http://cpsievert.github.io/pitchRx/

Comment: At the moment, your question is a bit fuzzy. R can connect to remote databases using the `RMySQL` or `RODBC` packages.  What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?  Please try to be specific about the problems that you are having.

Comment: First, I have never really used R. That said, I have tried to install RMySQL with no luck.  RODBC will install as a package. SO I started to go with RODBC, but the docs are confusing to me. after installing RODBC I have tried:

`dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=MySQL 5.5; Server=LahmanDB.db.6663351.hostedresource.com; Database=LahmanDB; Uid=LahmanDB; Pwd=Qwerty1!")' , but get the error
'Error: could not find function "odbcDriverConnect"`

Comment: @RichieCotton I have tried RODBC with the pathetic above statement.  I have heard RMySQL is easier, but hard to implement on WINDOWS.  Seems like Linux is the best for RMySQL,but I think that is just because MySQL runs off a linux based "server".  I have a remote linux server already, so do you know how to install and setup on PC?

Comment: Did you load the package using `library(RODBC)`?

Comment: For `RMySQL`, read why there is no binary version of the package available. http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/ReadMe On Windows, you need to install `Rtools` and build the package from source. Also, read the installation guide http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/INSTALL